# react how to make a pagination in external api

Tags: reactjs

Please need help paginating the results of information in an external API (pokeapi.co) I can fetch all the items, I have limited the answers to one hundred units and now I want to page ten out of ten per page but have the following error , when I click pagination links to switch pages and the items still don't appear as paginated.

Please, can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination';
    import PokemonCard from './PokemonCard';

    require ('bootstrap-less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less');

    export default class PolemonList extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
      activePage: 1,
      pageNumber: 10
    };
   }

    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
    this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
  }

  state = {
    url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=100',
    pokemon: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=100');
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data['results'] })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => (
              <PokemonCard
                key={pokemon.name}
                name={pokemon.name}
                url={pokemon.url}
              />
              ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
              <h2>Loading Pokemon</h2>
        )}
        <hr></hr>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12 text-center">
            <Pagination
              activePage={this.state.activePage}
              itemsCountPerPage={8}
              totalItemsCount={100}
              pageRangeDisplayed={10}
              onChange={this.handlePageChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Error below:

**this.setState is not a function in line 21 of the code that I list.**

Comment: Why are you initialising state twice, I mean in the constructor you initialising a state for activePage & pageNumber and again outside you are doing it for url & pokemon, why don't you initialise url as well as pokemon in contructor as well and give it a try. If it fails even again we look to it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is valid, so there must be an error with your build/project setup or some other issue.

Comment: And by "valid" I mean there shouldn't be an "this.setState is not a function in line 21 of the code that I list." your pagination code isn't doing anything however. 

Your "handlePageChange" function is setting the active page correctly, but you also need to load different pokemon in that function and set the state to the new group of pokemon.